# Liquid floating on top of water due to density or insolubility?

Tags: water, solubility, density

When a liquid is floating on top of water, how can one tell whether it is because of its insolubility in water or because it has lower density than water?

Comment: If it is insoluble and more dense then it will settle down

Comment: Is a crocodile long _or_ green?

Answer (score 2):

Both are contributing factors.

The **insolubility** ensures that it does not mix with water.

The **lower density of the liquid on top** ensures that it stays on top of the water instead of below the water.

Answer (score 1):

Sand is insoluble with water and when you mix it with water you see sand particles in the bottom of the water container, while when we  put hot water in cold water "water is soluble in water obviously" hot water float at the top of cold water due to the difference in density. So to make things clear, insoluble liquids which have more density than water stay at the bottom and form a heterogeneous mixture of the container while insoluble liquids which have less density than water float on top of the water and form a heterogeneous mixture and soluble substances mix with the water to form a homogeneous mixture